# Passing GET parameters mvc 4 in .cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, get

I am rather new to mvc, and I'm making some pagination for my website.
I would like to know how I can access the GET parameters from my url, so I can do some action like this:

```
@html.Actionlink("next page", "index", "someController", null, ?searchvalue1=GETPARAM1&searchvalue2=GETPARAM2&page=GETPARAM3 + 1)
```

The url would be something like

> http://www.something.com/controller?searchvalue1=foo&searchvalue2=bar&page=1

is this possible or is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want would be this:

```
@html.Actionlink("next page", "index", "someController", new { 
  searchvalue1=Request["searchvalue1"],
  searchvalue2=Request["searchvalue2"],
  page=Convert.ToInt32(Request["page"]) + 1
})
```

The properties in the anonymous object passed as the last parameter are the names of the GET variables and their values are the values passed in the URL.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt - You're right, updated my answer - you can simply use the `Request` object to access the `GET` parameters, although ideally the controller should be putting those into the Model to make things more testable.

Answer (score 3):

use QueryString ,  like:

```
@{
    string searchvalue1= Request.QueryString["searchvalue1"];
    string searchvalue2= Request.QueryString["searchvalue2"];
    string page= Request.QueryString["page"];
}
```

source:
[Send and Receive data in .cshtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920362/send-and-receive-data-in-cshtml-page)

it works with me ,

Answer (score 0):

To *access* the values in the controller, you will need to add corresponding arguments to your controller action. Here's a pagination action method I've used before:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string sort = Schools.DefaultSort, string sortDir = SortConstants.Ascending)
{
    // action code goes here
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more.